# Clicking a button opens an alert box and displays ruby method output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a list of servers with their names and the status of whether they are up or not by pinging them.

However, because there are 2-300 different servers, it takes a while for the Ping requests to complete and display the page, hence I want to improve it by using a button which the user clicks, which then opens up an alert box informing the user whether the server is Up and running or not.

I've already got a ruby method to do the testing, however when I do

```
<%= button_to_function "Status", "alert(serverUp?)" %>
```

the button on my form doesn't do anything. Is it because it only recognises JS as the action?
Would really like to get some help with it.

Otherwise, if anyone has any better idea of displaying the main page quickly, and then asynchronously run the `serverUp?` method so that the results are dynamically displayed in the table and it doesn't slow the page down to be displayed, I'd be grateful.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't run Ruby code `onclick`. Think of it like this: your app handles the browser's request, runs the controller, interpolates the Ruby into the `.erb` view file - producing plain text - and then sends that back over the wire to the browser. The browser has no idea what your server is running; it just interprets the `onclick` event as Javascript to be run.

If you want to asynchronously load the results into a pre-displayed table, you definitely can. Set up a controller action which runs the ping and returns the result (in text format), and have the `onclick` of the button (or a script run on load of the page) call that method. You should be able to use `link_to :remote => true` (or `link_to_remote` for Rails 2.x) - check your documentation.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the data in the table should be read first, the results should be saved somewhere (text file?), and then the results should be read in. Wouldn't the whole reading/saving/loading process take a while as well? Maybe I'm just not 100% clear on what you mean. Are there any examples of that available for me to get a rough idea?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. You could have your rendered view consist of a table with no results in, plus either a set of buttons which `onclick` make an AJAX request to your app for one particular server state; or a javascript routine which runs on load and AJAX requests all the states, to be filled in as they come back. I don't know OTTOMH of an example.

Comment: I like the second part of the idea, but have never done it before. Probably need some guidance on how to do it and make it effective. Also, where would I place the code? in the model or controller class? or a total different class by itself?

Comment: It's surprisingly easy, especially as you can use [`<%= remote_function %>`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/remote_function) to generate the needed javascript. The Ruby code will kick off in your Controller - remember that all your browser can do is sent and HTTP request, which will always cause a Controller action to happen. Hopefully you've got enough to Google about now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `serverup?` method works fine you might assign its result to some instance variable in controller and later use it in view as following

```
<%= button_to_function "Status", "alert('#{some_var}')" %>
```

**Edit** or without rails helpers

```
 <input type="button" value="submit" onclick=<%= "alert('#{@var}')" %>>
```

however it's value should mot include any `'` otherwise `escape_javascript` helper also have to be used

if you want update it with AJAX it might be sth like

```
$('#my_button').click(function() {
   $.post('/server_status/1', {}, function(response) { 
      alert(response);
   }
});
```

Comment: where would I place the second part of the code?
i tried the first code, using the instance variable, but somehow it doesn't seem to work as expected, and the alert box is empty. Tried making it global, but that didn't work either.

Comment: to use second JS you have to use jQuery and place that code inside `$(function(){ ... });` in your view